# Десериализация пустого массива

Tags: c#, json, .net

Проблема вот в чем.
У меня есть класс

```cs
public class Sparkline
{
    public List<double> data { get; set; }
    public double totalChange { get; set; }
}
```

Вообще много классов, но проблема именно в этом.
Вот такой json работает нормально

```json
"sparkline": { "data": [ 0, 0, 10.95, 8.27, 11.43, 12.5, 14.29 ], "totalChange": 14.29 },
```

Но есть объекты которые приходят пустые

```json
"sparkline": {
"data": [],
"totalChange": 0
},
```

На сколько я понимаю из за того что Лист пустой вылетает эксепшн.

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Double.
Path: $.lines[12].sparkline.data[0] | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 9142."
```

Ну я подумал если там ничего нет то может быть можно разрешить null значения.

```cs
public List<double>? data { get; set; }
```

Не сработало.
Использую `System.Text.Json;`
Собственно как пофиксить?

Comment: А вы уверены, что дело в массиве? Ибо у меня лично ваш JSON (заголовок убрал) без проблем [десериализуется](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hn0QHf).

Comment: Я предполагаю) Вот мой не рабочий код со всеми классами https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDDlIQ

Comment: `lines[12].sparkline.data[0]` - посмотрите, что у вас там [находится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYBK.png), то есть дело не в пустом массиве, а в том, что массив иногда содержит `null` объекты, а значит `List<double>` -> `List<double?>`.

Comment: Точно, спасибо. Я не там `?` поставил) Оформите как ответ, я отмечу.

Comment: Ответ можете написать сами. Поглядел я, кстати, на ваш код и заметил много лишнего и странного. Не дублируйте классы, у вас несколько классов имеют одинаковые свойства, используйте 1! Дальше, имена, в C# принято публичные данные писать с заглавной буквы, слитно, без каких-либо подчеркиваний и прочего, то есть `SomeValue`, а не `some_value`. Чтоб это сделать, воспользуйтесь атрибутом `JsonPropertyName`. Далее, `HttpClient` - он должен быть ОДИН на все приложение, не создавайте его постоянно! Ну и напоследок, для `HttpClient` есть расширение `GetFromJsonAsync`, которое сразу десериализует.

Comment: То есть, должно быть [нечто такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LKyQAk) (не все классы причесывать стал). А, ну и помните, вы не обязаны прописывать все свойства, которые даются вам через JSON, берите только нужное (я уверен, что 90% данных вам там попросту не нужны).

Comment: Ну да, большая часть не нужна. Я классы через конвентр создавал, что он мне дал то я и скопипастил)

Comment: Не копируйте слепо то, что вам дают программы, думайте, что там и как. Вон, к примеру, если вам нужен только `ChaosValue`, то достаточной [такой структуры](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eUwsdM), всего пару строк кода) Короче, берегите свое время, будьте "ленивым" программистом (в хорошем смысле этого слова).

Answer (score 0):

Ну я просто добавил на свойства которые приходят пустые атрибут `[JsonIgnore]`.
Но это затычка.